# NoReverseMatch Exception Value Reverse for 'books_recsys_app.views.home' not found

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am making a movie recommender app. This error occurs when searching for a movie in views.py.

views.py

```
data = post_data.get('data', None)
if data:
    return redirect('%s?%s' % (reverse('books_recsys_app.views.home'),urllib.urlencode({'q': data})))
```

urls.py

```
app_name = "books_recsys_app"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
    url(r'^$', books_recsys_app.views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^auth/', books_recsys_app.views.auth, name='auth'),   
    url(r'^signout/',books_recsys_app.views.signout,name='signout'),
    url(r'^rate_movie/',books_recsys_app.views.rate_movie,name='rate_movie'),
    url(r'^movies-recs/',books_recsys_app.views.movies_recs,name='movies_recs'),
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^users-list/',UsersList.as_view(),name='users-list')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Django 1.8 you shouldn't use the dotted python path to reverse URLs. Use the *name* from the URL pattern instead:

```
reverse('books_recsys_app:home')
```

The `books_recsys_app:` namespace is required since you have `app_name = "books_recsys_app"` in your `urls.py`.

Comment: it shows the error 'books_recsys_app' is not a registered namespace  when changed to your recommendation

Comment: You have `app_name = "books_recsys_app"`, so `reverse('books_recsys_app:home')` should not give a namespace error. If you are using a really old, out of date version of Django then perhaps `reverse('home')` without the namespace would work.

Comment: Thank you , this solved my problem although my Django has version 2.1.4.

Comment: If you have `app_name = "books_recsys_app"`, then `reverse('books_recsys_app:home')` should work in Django 2.1.4. Perhaps you have unsaved changes, haven't restarted the server since making changes, or are running different code for some other reason.